# PoE Query - IP Phones

Tags: power-over-ethernet, telephony

My company have signed up for BT Business Broadband. We have IP Phones supplied by an external company. We have been led to believe that BT Business Broadband blocks IP Phones other than their own. Is this true?

Also, we have foolishly bought a switch for 28 computers/phones, but didn't think of PoE (Particularly handy for cable management). To be honest Web Development is more our bag and we know base network stuff.

Anyways, The 28-port switch, We are thinking of noting down each port the IP phone is plugged into, and then route that to a switch with PoE capabilities. Would this then power the phones, or would the original switch need to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question:

> We have been led to believe that BT Business Broadband blocks IP
>   Phones other than their own. Is this true?

is off topic here. You will need to ask BT, but it doesn't matter if you are not going to send VoIP traffic over the BT network (outside of your network).

If your phones need PoE, they must be directly connected to a PoE switch, or you can use an inline power injector between the switch and the phone. Also, most PoE phones can use an external power adapter.

Answer (score 2):

Where do you live? If it's US they aren't allowed to do that legally. All you'll have to do is find a SIP provider and have your Call Manager of whatever flavor register to it. You may run into QoS issues using just standard ISP broadband though with latency and jitter.

PoE is industry standard so almost any PoE switch will be able to power it, make sure you know the phone wattage and the power supply capabilities of the switch though because some may have all PoE ports but the power supply limits the amount of active ports to 24.

Comment: Hi @Fallacy11 I'm based in the UK. Will check the switch we've bought. See if it does indeed have PoE capabilities

Comment: I would assume this in the UK since the ISP is British Telecom.